# Multiple lines in a cell in a datagrid view

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using C#  .net..  in that I'm working with windows form application

I have a datagrid view with two columns. the first column is readonly and the other is editable. now I want every cell of the second column to support for multilines in each cell. I want to press enter key and come to the next line in the same cell. But now if I press enter key it is going to the next cell below it. I want the cursor to be in the next line of the same cell

Comment: as in my knowledge i think cell is single line object you just make space in words and after saving it your data will appear in wrap format.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can:

1. hook to the KeyDown event
2. check if Enter was hit, if true:
3. add a linebreak to the cell's string value, and:
4. mark the event has handled by setting e.SuppressKeyPress to True